# how to use nested array in while loop?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I want to put data in array which then put in excel file but it does not work.

```
    $sql="SELECT `Jobc_id`, `Customer_name`, `Veh_reg_no`, `MSI_cat`, `Mileage` FROM `jobcard`";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

    array( $row["job_id"],$row["Customer_name"],$row["Veh_reg_no"],$row["MSI_cat"],$row["Mileage"]);
}
foreach($rows as $row)
    $writer->writeSheetRow('Sheet1', $row);
```

Whereas, below code work..

```
$rows = array(
    array('2003','1','-50.5','2010-01-01 23:00:00','2012-12-31 23:00:00'),
    array('2003','B1', '23.5','2010-01-01 00:00:00','2012-12-31 00:00:00'),
); 
 foreach($rows as $row)
        $writer->writeSheetRow('Sheet1', $row);
```

How can I make first code to work :(
pls help

Comment: You never assign a name to the array

Comment: ^^ Or rather you never assign the array to a variable.

Comment: "_it does not work_" We get this a lot. Do you get any errors? Where do you set `$rows` in your first code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not assigning the array to a variable, therefore you can't access your fetched data after the while loop. This should fix it:

```
$rows = [];
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $rows[] = [$row["job_id"],$row["Customer_name"],$row["Veh_reg_no"],$row["MSI_cat"],$row["Mileage"]];
}
// now you can use $rows
```